# How to run the .als files using .bat file on Windows 10 so it can produce the values in the text files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run images file `.als` using the `file_combine.bat`

When I run this, I should be seeing the values appearing in the new text files but I am getting blanks. I'm using **Windows Pro 10**. I have tried switching from `LF` to `CRLF`, changed the encoding to `UTF-8` but no luck. any suggestions?

```
rem ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem file_cmb [ŒŸõŒê1] [ŒŸõŒê2] [ŒŸõŒê3]EEE[ŒŸõŒê9] 
rem ŒŸõŒê–ˆiÅ‘å9Œêj‚ÉƒtƒHƒ‹ƒ_’†‚Ìƒtƒ@ƒCƒ‹‚ðŒ‹‡‚·‚éB
rem ‚»‚ÌŒãbin=1 NGƒf[ƒ^‚Ì‚Ý‚ðƒtƒBƒ‹ƒ^o—Í
rem ŒŸõŒê‚ª‚È‚¢Žž‚Í‚Í‘S‚Ä‚Ìƒtƒ@ƒCƒ‹‚ÌNGƒf[ƒ^‚ð‚Ü‚Æ‚ß‚Äo—Í
rem ŒŸõŒê1‚ðsam ŒŸõŒê2‚ðavi ŒŸõŒê3‚ð.txt ŒŸõŒê4‚ð.csv ‚µ‚½‚¢ê‡ˆÈ‰º‚Ì—l‚É‹Lq‚·‚é
rem file_cmb sam avi .txt .csv
rem 20201022 Windows‚Ì‰üs‚àˆ—‚Å‚«‚é‚æ‚¤‚É!ET!‚ðŒ©‚És‚­—l‚É‚µ‚½A¡‚Ü‚Å‚Í!LF!‚Ì‚Ý‚Ìˆ—
rem 20201022 ‘Sƒtƒ@ƒCƒ‹ŒŸõŽž‚Ézip‚àƒtƒBƒ‹ƒ^‚·‚é‚æ‚¤‚É‚µ‚½
rem ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
call :ET
call :file_cmbin avi sam
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
exit
    
rem ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
:file_cmbin
del all_*.txt>nul 2>&1
del __tmp>nul 2>&1
    
set wd1=%1&set wd2=%2&set wd3=%3&set wd4=%4&set wd5=%5&set wd6=%6&set wd7=%7&set wd8=%8&set wd9=%9&set blank=
    
for /L %%I in (1,1,9) do (
       if !wd%%I!==!blank! (
          set /a loop_cnt=%%I-1&goto :loop_out
      )
)
:loop_out

if !loop_cnt!==0 (
    type nul>__tmp
    for /f %%A in ('dir /b^|findstr /v ".bat .xlsx .xls .xlsm .zip"') do (
        copy /b __tmp+"%%A"
)
        findstr "1!LF!" __tmp>all_files_NG.txt
    for %%F in (all_files_NG.txt) do (
        if %%~zF==0 (
          findstr "1!ET!" __tmp>all_files_NG.txt
    )
  )
del __tmp>nul 2>&1
)
    
for /L %%I in (1,1,!loop_cnt!) do (
      copy /b *!wd%%I!* __tmp
      findstr "1!LF!" __tmp>all_!wd%%I!_NG.txt
for %%G in (all_!wd%%I!_NG.txt) do (
      if %%~zG==0 (
        findstr "1!ET!" __tmp>all_!wd%%I!_NG.txt
     )
 )
del __tmp>nul 2>&1
)
exit /b

:ET
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cmd /u /c echo;–¼') do (
     set CR=%%a&set CR=!CR:~0,1!
    )
set LF=^
    
    
set ET=!CR!!LF!
exit /b
    
rem ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: `if !wd%%I!==!blank!` won't work. Use `if "!wd%%I!"==""`

Comment: To begin with, you should change your `rem` lines to `@rem`. You also need to explain what you mean by "switching LF to CRLF", and what "UTD8" "encoding" is. I'd also like to know what the [[tag:notepad++]] tag relates too!

Comment: forgive my lack of knowledge in the programming, i am new to the scene. I was told the problem is caused by original file being rewritten so the location of the change is the new line code LF. The batch file for the command prompt is a dedicated application for the windows OS. The new code must be enter. The new line code is different so it seems we thought this is the reason why it was not running properly but it doesnt seem to be the case.

Comment: Did you read all of my previous comment?

Comment: no, I don't know what is UTD 8 encoding.

The notepad++ is used to create a .batfile so i can run a marco on .als files. It combines the .als files extracting the values and then produces the results into .txt files.

Comment: It is [`UTF-8`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding, not `UTD-8`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake you're right gerhard, thanks for correcting it.

Comment: @Stephan, `if !wd%%I!==!blank!` works, given that variable `blank` is not defined, though I totally agree with your suggestion of using quotes…

Comment: @aschipfl: uh - you are right. But It would be parsed as `if something== (command block)` so I was so sure that I didn't even check. Batch seems to never stop to both amaze and horrify me. It's creepy..

Comment: @Stephan, the key is delayed expansion here and the fact that tokenisation of the `if` command line occurs earlier, so there appears to be a valid (non-empty) token at the moment when syntax errors are detected. It becomes even more interesting when doing a numeric comparison like `if 0 equ !! echo Yes.`, which indeed returns `Yes.`, since the eventually empty token `!!` is apparently interpreted as zero…

Comment: @aschipfl What I said: creepy `:D`

Comment: This code is behaving strangely because it works on some sub-folders containing all .als files and doesn't on other sub-folders despite being in the same main folder.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of line 24 : `set blank=`
This should be : `set blank=` 
Probably some editor made this trailing space disappear.
Better is to define blank within double quot's `set "blank= "`